# Mysterious logging.basicConfig problem (Python)

Tags: python, logging

I'm writing a Python script to retrieve data from Flickr. For logging purposes, I have the following setup function:

```
def init_log(logfile):
    format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,level=logging.DEBUG,format=format)
```

I've tested this using the python shell and it works as expected, creating a file if one doesn't already exist. But calling it from within my program is where it stops working. The function is definitely being called, and the `logfile` parameter is working properly – `logging.basicConfig` just isn't creating any file. I'm not even getting any errors or warnings.

My use of the Python Flickr API may be the culprit, but I doubt it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The `logging.basicConfig` function only does anything if the root logger has no handlers configured. If called when there are already some handlers attached to the root, it's basically a no-op (as is documented).

Possibly the Python Flickr API does some logging, in which case you may find that basicConfig should be called earlier in your code.

Comment: Thanks! After opening dozens of stackoverflow questions, your answer was the one that helped me. I don't know what lib or commit caused this to stop working, I didn't see anything messing the logging from the latest commits. But just moving my logger setup to the start of my script (instead of inside a main function) solved my problems.